# Tag writing on android practical running examples or code

Tags: android, nfc

I have gone through various discussions on Stack Overflow about Tag writing. But did not find any practical examples with code that can help me to build functionality to write on tag using Android NFC functionality.

I am trying to build Tag Writing functionality on Android Jelly Bean. 
But did not able to write on tag.

Could any one please help me providing some sample codes or examples??

Thanks for your sharing.

Comment: There are many different types of tags,suitable for different applications. What kind of tag or what kind of data do you want to write?

Answer (score 0):

See the [NDEF Tools for Android](http://code.google.com/p/ndef-tools-for-android/) project which I've created. It contains code for reading, writing and beaming on Android. Also see the [NFC Eclipse plugin](http://code.google.com/p/nfc-eclipse-plugin/) which is good for learning the NDEF format.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do to write a tag using Nfc utility classes for Android that I published [here](https://gist.github.com/germanviscuso/1595378):

```
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        // Tag writing mode
        if (writeMode && nfcUtil.checkTagIntentMatch(intent)) {
            Tag detectedTag = nfcUtil.getTag(intent);
            try {
                Util.playSound(this);
            } catch (Exception e) { }
            nfcUtil.writeTag(movie.asNdef(), detectedTag);
        }
    }
```